# Tensorflow how to transfer a 1-D tensor to vector

Tags: tensorflow

I'm a total beginner to TensorFlow, now I have a 1-D tensor, its shape is [4,  1], I have 2 matrix
`a=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[4,2]);
    b=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[2])`
when I multiple them: `c=tf.mul(a,tf.expand_dims(b,1))`

then I got a [4,1] matrix c.  it is a 2-D tensor, but I want to change it to a 1-D tensor , means it's a vector and its shape is [4],  not [4,1].

tf.shape shows that  `tf.shape[c]=[4 1],not [4]`

Can anyone tell me how to do this?  thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#squeeze) or [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#reshape).

```
a = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[4, 2])
b = tf.constant(1.0, shape=[2])
c = tf.matmul(a, tf.expand_dims(b,1))
c = tf.squeeze(c)

# This will also work:
# c = tf.reshape(c, [4])
```

You also want [tf.matmul](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#matmul) instead of [tf.mul](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#mul) in your example if you want to do matrix multiplication instead of elementwise multiplication.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works.    By the way, I input wrong word.  It is "tf.matmul(a,tf.expand_dims(b,1))", not tf.mul(a,tf.expand_dims(b,1)).     You are right.